# how to remove the appended value if unchecked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, checkbox

here is my script i check the tr will append for view and i want to remove that when i click uncheck.

[image: css 3 has to be removed because have unchecked it.]

[image: check and uncheck is happening from here]

```
$("#jobSkills").on('change', '.selectPiSkill', function() {
    var count = $(this).attr('count');
    if (this.checked) {
        var title = $('#skill_' + count + '_title').val();
        var weightage = $('#skill_' + count + '_weightage').val();
        $('#PiSkills tr:last').after('<tr class="' + count + '"><td class="col-xs-4"><input value="' + title + '" readonly class="form-control text-center"></td><td class="col-xs-4"><input value="' + weightage + '" readonly class="form-control text-center" type="text"></td></tr>');
    } else {
        //unchecked remove tr
        $('#PiSkills tr.' + count).remove();
    }
});
```

```html
<table id="PiSkills" class="table table-responsive" style="margin-bottom:5px">
    <tr>
        <th width="450"><input type="text" readonly value="Skill" class="form-control text-center">  </th>
        <th width="450"><input type="text" readonly value="Weightage(%)" class="form-control text-center"> </th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for.

Below is the example to remove row in table

HTML

```
<table class='test'>
<tr>
  <th>Name</th>
  <th>Test 1</th>
  <th>Test 2</th>
  <th>Optional</th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>A</td>
  <td><input class='test1' type="checkbox"></td>
  <td><input class='test2' type="checkbox" checked="checked"></td>
  <td><button class='opt1'>REMOVE</button></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>B</td>
  <td><input class='test1' type="checkbox"></td>
  <td><input class='test2' type="checkbox"></td>
  <td><button class='opt1'>REMOVE</button></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>C</td>
  <td><input class='test1' type="checkbox"></td>
  <td><input class='test2' type="checkbox" checked="checked"></td>
  <td><button class='opt1'>REMOVE</button></td>
</tr>
</table>
<br>
<div class='result'>

</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$(".opt1").on("click",function(){
  var q = $(this);
  $(".result").css("border","1px solid red").html(q.parents("tr").html()).append( "<b>This row has been removed</b>" );
  q.parents("tr").remove();
});

$(".test2").on("click",function(){
  var q = $(this);

  if(!q.is(":checked")){
    $(".result").css("border","1px solid red").html(q.parents("tr").html()).append( "<b>This row has been removed</b>" );
    q.parents("tr").remove();
  }else{
    alert("CHECKED");
    $(".result").text("NEW CHECKED");
  }

});
```

And the example in jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/synz/ot2jp5uL/

@ this 1? : https://jsfiddle.net/synz/zwom17uw/2/

Comment: @abdul-waheed check this out.
maybe this is what are you looking for. :)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure but this might help, change

```
 $('#PiSkills tr').each(function(){
      if($(this).attr('class') == count){
       $(this).remove();
      }
   })
```

Comment: my question is differnt you see i have added 2 images if i uncheck from image 2 image 1 <tr> has to be deleted.

Comment: So you are saying if you check remove from CSS 3 in image 2 then CSS 3 <tr> from image 1 will be removed

Comment: Exactly that is what i am looking for

Comment: try this  $('#PiSkills tr').each(function(){})